# How to fix 'exports/require is not defined' from bundle.js after RXJS6 update in Angular 7 app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, rxjs

Recently I was updating **Angular 5.1** ASP.NET application with **RXJS 5** to latest **Angular 7.2** with **RXJS 6.3** With all this I also updated **typescript from 2.8 to 3.2**
At the end everything worked as expected, until I tried to run applicaiton using bundles on production. I was geting an error: **'ReferenceError: exports is not defined'**

I tried to solve this error with simply defining exports to script tag:

```
<script> var exports = {}; </script>
```

which seems like an ughly hack but it did the job.
After that I got another error:
**'ReferenceError: require is not defined'**
I started to dig deeper and I found out that bundle.js contains something that looks like uncompiled code

new bundle.js contains this:

```
    function nO(n, l) {
        return n(l = {
            exports: {}
        }, l.exports), l.exports
    }
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
        value: !0
    });
    var lO = require("rxjs");
    exports.Observable = lO.Observable, exports.Subject = lO.Subject;
    var eO = require("rxjs/internal-compatibility");
    exports.AnonymousSubject = eO.AnonymousSubject;
    var tO = require("rxjs/internal-compatibility");
    exports.config = tO.config, require("./add/observable/bindCallback"), require("./add/observable/bindNodeCallback"), require("./add/observable/combineLatest"), require("./add/observable/concat"), require("./add/observable/defer"), require("./add/observable/empty"), require("./add/observable/forkJoin"), require("./add/observable/from"), require("./add/observable/fromEvent"), require("./add/observable/fromEventPattern"), require("./add/observable/fromPromise"), require("./add/observable/generate"), require("./add/observable/if"), require("./add/observable/interval"), require("./add/observable/merge"), require("./add/observable/race"), require("./add/observable/never"), require("./add/observable/of"), require("./add/observable/onErrorResumeNext"), require("./add/observable/pairs"), require("./add/observable/range"), require("./add/observable/using"), require("./add/observable/throw"), require("./add/observable/timer"), require("./add/observable/zip"), require("./add/observable/dom/ajax"), require("./add/observable/dom/webSocket"), require("./add/operator/buffer"), require("./add/operator/bufferCount"), require("./add/operator/bufferTime"), require("./add/operator/bufferToggle"), require("./add/operator/bufferWhen"), require("./add/operator/catch"), require("./add/operator/combineAll"), require("./add/operator/combineLatest"), require("./add/operator/concat"), require("./add/operator/concatAll"), require("./add/operator/concatMap"), require("./add/operator/concatMapTo"), require("./add/operator/count"), require("./add/operator/dematerialize"), require("./add/operator/debounce"), require("./add/operator/debounceTime"), require("./add/operator/defaultIfEmpty"), require("./add/operator/delay"), require("./add/operator/delayWhen"), require("./add/operator/distinct"), require("./add/operator/distinctUntilChanged"), require("./add/operator/distinctUntilKeyChanged"), require("./add/operator/do"), require("./add/operator/exhaust"), require("./add/operator/exhaustMap"), require("./add/operator/expand"), require("./add/operator/elementAt"), require("./add/operator/filter"), require("./add/operator/finally"), require("./add/operator/find"), require("./add/operator/findIndex"), require("./add/operator/first"), require("./add/operator/groupBy"), require("./add/operator/ignoreElements"), require("./add/operator/isEmpty"), require("./add/operator/audit"), require("./add/operator/auditTime"), require("./add/operator/last"), require("./add/operator/let"), require("./add/operator/every"), require("./add/operator/map"), require("./add/operator/mapTo"), require("./add/operator/materialize"), require("./add/operator/max"), require("./add/operator/merge"), require("./add/operator/mergeAll"), require("./add/operator/mergeMap"), require("./add/operator/mergeMapTo"), require("./add/operator/mergeScan"), require("./add/operator/min"), require("./add/operator/multicast"), require("./add/operator/observeOn"), require("./add/operator/onErrorResumeNext"), require("./add/operator/pairwise"), require("./add/operator/partition"), require("./add/operator/pluck"), require("./add/operator/publish"), require("./add/operator/publishBehavior"), require("./add/operator/publishReplay"), require("./add/operator/publishLast"), require("./add/operator/race"), require("./add/operator/reduce"), require("./add/operator/repeat"), require("./add/operator/repeatWhen"), require("./add/operator/retry"), require("./add/operator/retryWhen"), require("./add/operator/sample"), require("./add/operator/sampleTime"), require("./add/operator/scan"), require("./add/operator/sequenceEqual"), require("./add/operator/share"), require("./add/operator/shareReplay"), require("./add/operator/single"), require("./add/operator/skip"), require("./add/operator/skipLast"), require("./add/operator/skipUntil"), require("./add/operator/skipWhile"), require("./add/operator/startWith"), require("./add/operator/subscribeOn"), require("./add/operator/switch"), require("./add/operator/switchMap"), require("./add/operator/switchMapTo"), require("./add/operator/take"), require("./add/operator/takeLast"), require("./add/operator/takeUntil"), require("./add/operator/takeWhile"), require("./add/operator/throttle"), require("./add/operator/throttleTime"), require("./add/operator/timeInterval"), require("./add/operator/timeout"), require("./add/operator/timeoutWith"), require("./add/operator/timestamp"), require("./add/operator/toArray"), require("./add/operator/toPromise"), require("./add/operator/window"), require("./add/operator/windowCount"), require("./add/operator/windowTime"), require("./add/operator/windowToggle"), require("./add/operator/windowWhen"), require("./add/operator/withLatestFrom"), require("./add/operator/zip"), require("./add/operator/zipAll");
    var iO = require("rxjs");
    exports.Subscription = iO.Subscription, exports.ReplaySubject = iO.ReplaySubject, exports.BehaviorSubject = iO.BehaviorSubject, exports.Notification = iO.Notification, exports.EmptyError = iO.EmptyError, exports.ArgumentOutOfRangeError = iO.ArgumentOutOfRangeError, exports.ObjectUnsubscribedError = iO.ObjectUnsubscribedError, exports.UnsubscriptionError = iO.UnsubscriptionError, exports.pipe = iO.pipe;
    var uO = require("rxjs/testing");
    exports.TestScheduler = uO.TestScheduler;
    var oO = require("rxjs");
    exports.Subscriber = oO.Subscriber, exports.AsyncSubject = oO.AsyncSubject, exports.ConnectableObservable = oO.ConnectableObservable, exports.TimeoutError = oO.TimeoutError, exports.VirtualTimeScheduler = oO.VirtualTimeScheduler;
    var rO = require("rxjs/ajax");
    exports.AjaxResponse = rO.AjaxResponse, exports.AjaxError = rO.AjaxError, exports.AjaxTimeoutError = rO.AjaxTimeoutError;
    var sO = require("rxjs"),
        aO = require("rxjs/internal-compatibility"),
        cO = require("rxjs/internal-compatibility");
    exports.TimeInterval = cO.TimeInterval, exports.Timestamp = cO.Timestamp;
    var dO = require("rxjs/operators");
    exports.operators = dO;
    var pO = {
        asap: sO.asapScheduler,
        queue: sO.queueScheduler,
        animationFrame: sO.animationFrameScheduler,
        async: sO.asyncScheduler
    };
```

Base on that I realized something is wrong with compiling rxjs to my bundle.js
Before update to latest version of angular, rxjs and typescript there was no mention of "rxjs" or any "require" statement in bundle.js.
So I first guessed this may be something new with RXJS6 or I forgot to do something somewhere.
I didn't do any drastic changes to tsconfig.js and I folowed all the update steps correctly.
Again, localy, using unbounded code everything works like a charm.

I wasn't able to find issue similar enough to learn from it or any mention of this behavior after update RXJS or typescript

I want to understand what happened here, why are there suddenly a lot of require statements in my bundle, and how to fix this issue.
*I would like to avoid implementing RequireJS if this isn't necessary. I guess app should work without it*
Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

There was quite a lot of changes between angular 5 and 7.
and also between rxjs 5 and 6.

You need to do quite a lot of steps to convert your codebase.

Fortunately angular has a good guide on how to do this.

https://update.angular.io

Make special note of the rxjs converter that converts between 5 and 6

```
npm install -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. All code is already converted, I was following the update guide and did all the things mentioned there. Including `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate`. Updated application works locally without any problems
I tried to run `rxjx-5-to-6-migrate` again but now I just get a message: **Cannot find any possible migrations**

Comment: angular cli has changes the output names.
It could be that you are missing the runtime.js file.